# Parsing data from particular XML file with PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I need to parse exchange rates from an XML file...problem is that  i've never seen an XML file written this way:

http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

Question is, how can i parse "currency" and "rate" from each `<Cube/>` child node?

I will then need to elaborate them with a PHP script

Comment: With SimpleXML or DomDocument. :)

Comment: can you show an example? normally i use this:
`$xml=simplexml_load_file("note.xml");
echo $xml->child1 . "<br>";
echo $xml->child2 . "<br>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access attributes with `simplexml`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
foreach ($xml->Cube->Cube->Cube As $c)
    echo "$c[currency]: $c[rate] <br />";
```

see it in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/SaoEdB

see `simplexml` explained: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php